# OData PATCH request results in IllegalArgumentException

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Since last week we started using SDK version 3.34.1 (and also tested this with 3.35.0). When we send a PATCH request to a SAP service we get a `HTTP 204 No-Content` response back from our SAP service (SAP Gateway). When the SDK tries to read that response, it tries to parse the response body which is empty. This leads to the following exception:

```
2020-12-17 16:13:51.767 ERROR 106363 --- [ut.sap.cases]-0] .s.c.s.d.o.c.r.ODataRequestResultGeneric : 
Failed to buffer HTTP response. Unable to buffer HTTP entity.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrapped entity may not be null
    at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.<init>(HttpEntityWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.<init>(BufferedHttpEntity.java:59)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataRequestResultGeneric.lambda$getHttpResponse$4f00ca4e$1(ODataRequestResultGeneric.java:180)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataRequestResultGeneric.getHttpResponse(ODataRequestResultGeneric.java:180)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataHealthyResponseValidator.requireHealthyResponse(ODataHealthyResponseValidator.java:44)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.andThenTry(Try.java:250)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataRequestGeneric.tryExecute(ODataRequestGeneric.java:194)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataRequestGeneric.tryExecuteWithCsrfToken(ODataRequestGeneric.java:225)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataRequestUpdate.execute(ODataRequestUpdate.java:136)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperUpdate.executeRequest(FluentHelperUpdate.java:372)
    at com.alliander.gvrn.pmd.adapter.out.sap.cases.SapCasesClient.updateCase(SapCasesClient.java:103)
    at com.alliander.gvrn.pmd.adapter.out.sap.cases.SapCasesClient.persistOn(SapCasesClient.java:81)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at ....
```

We use generated typed OData V2 client, which are generated by providing our EDMX files a per the SDK documentation.

Below a code snippet of the function that's calling the service. The `matrixCase` is a autogenerated object. The OData PATCH is properly handled by the SAP service.

```
private void updateCase(final ExternalId caseId, final PMDFlow pmdFlow, String jwtToken) {
        final HttpDestination sapMatrix = httpDestinationProvider.providePrincipalPropagationDestination(jwtToken);

        // "Create matrixCase object with key
        MatrixCase matrixCase = MatrixCase.builder()
                .psReference(caseId.getValue())
                .build();
        // Set PmdAppControl explicitly, otherwise the generated client doesn't know which fields are updated.
        matrixCase.setPMDAppControl(pmdFlow.getSapNotation());

        try {
            casesService
                    .updateMatrixCase(matrixCase)
                    .executeRequest(sapMatrix);
        } catch (ODataException e) {
            OdataLogger.logODataException(e);
            throw new SapClientException(e);
        }
    }
```

We've updated to SDK 3.34.1 due to other issues, however before we used 3.32.0 and I don't remember having this issue in version 3.32.0

Any ideas?

Danny

Comment: Hi Danny, Is this exception thrown or is it only logged? We see that the cloud sdk log this as an error which is why it ls leading to misinterpretations but this is an intended behaviour and cloud sdk would adapt the log level to rectify the confusion. So incase it is not thrown I say everything is fine.

Comment: I actually don't know. It thrown/logged before the catch statement in our code. And if it's normal behaviour, why log it at all. And why then log it as an error and an illegal argument exception?

Comment: In my opinion, the ODataHealthyResponseValidator should take HTTP 204 No-Content responses into account. Since they are completely normal according to the OData V2 specs. Why try to parse a response body if the HTTP status already tells you there's no body

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your observation is correct that 204 represents a valid answer and is not worth logging an error. Hence, the Cloud SDK team will adjust the log entry level to be less alarming.

Regards,
Tanvi

Comment: Based on https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#3360---january-14-2021 a new version 3.36.0 should have been release 4 days ago. However it's not available on maven central. When will this be available?

Comment: There was a bit of delay but the version is available on maven central since 19 Jan. https://github.wdf.sap.corp/cloudsdk/sdk-core/issues/331